# Purpose of build "configurations"?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I tried running the following commands in my project directory:

```
dotnet build -c Debug
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet build -c qwerty
```

.NET created three directories (Debug, Release, qwerty) with practically identical contents, the only difference was the configuration name in the metadata. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Depends what you have configured in you VS project. F.e. "Optimize code" on Release or other stuff. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2022)

Comment: `practically identical contents` not really. Different configurations use different settings. The `Release` configuration uses optimizations that aren't enabled in Debug builds and doesn't contain the debug symbols and code generated by the Debug build. There's a significant performance difference between Debug and Release builds. It's no different than any other language or build syste

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I skimmed through the contents of the binaries, the only difference was in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

The difference for different build configurations is that, for different build configuration it may generate different dll and codes.

For example, if you want to debug the application inside the remote server, you should build it as the debug and it will contain related file.

Then inside the codes, we could check the environment to decide if we should enable the customer error page or not.

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline. Is development means the debug
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Comment: The _contents_ of the binaries was identical, the only difference was the name of the configuration in the metadata.

Comment: The debug will contains the different pdb file which contains more information like code line.  The release mode will also generate the pdb file, but its pdf file will not contains these information.